# NASM. error: comma expected after operand 1

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

So I'm trying to assemble this, but when I try, it gives me error: comma expected after operand 1

Here is the code.

```
option_screen:
mov ax, os_init_msg     ; Set up the welcome screen
mov bx, os_version_msg
mov cx, 10011111b       ; Colour: white text on light blue
call os_draw_background

mov ax, dialog_string_1     ; Ask if user wants app selector or command-line
mov bx, dialog_string_2
mov dx, 1           ; We want a two-option dialog box (OK or Cancel)
call os_dialog_box

cmp ax, 1           ; If OK (option 0) chosen, start app selector
jne near app_selector

call os_clear_screen        ; Otherwise clean screen and start the CLI
call os_command_line

jmp option_screen       ; Offer menu/CLI choice after CLI has exited


; Data for the above code...

os_init_msg     db 'Welcome to 0x539's OS!', 0
os_version_msg      db 'Version ', OS_VER, 10

dialog_string_1     db 'Thanks for trying out MikeOS!', 0
dialog_string_2     db 'This project is currently in Alpha version.', 0
```

The error occurs at the `os_init_msg` line. 
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a single quote inside your string, which makes the assembler think you've entered the string `'Welcome to 0x539'`, followed by the characters `s OS!', 0`.

Use double quotes as delimiters instead: `"Welcome to 0x539's OS!", 0`.